# Visual Studio cannot find debuggerutils.h

Tags: visual-studio, c++-winrt

I've installed Visual Studio 15.9.0, Preview 3 and created a project using the new platform support for C++/winrt. The project runs fine until I set a breakpoint. When the break is hit VS tells me "You need to find debuggerutils.h to view the source for the current call stack frame" It tells me this file was originally at onecore\com\combase\inc\debuggerutils.h, though it doesn't tell me the path to onecore. Search can't find such a file. Does anyone know how to find that file or install it? I had just assumed that VS would automatically include debugging capability.
[Update] Appears it is not the setting of a breakpoint but a bug causing a break before that. But I'm still mystified by the error message.

Comment: p.s. Even with an app that runs fine without breakpoints, I get this message if I attempt to place a breakpoint in a coroutine. Isn't this a spurious error message?

Answer (score 0):

Someone asked this question on github's WinObjC issues:
https://github.com/microsoft/WinObjC/issues/2931
From the discussion:
edvv commented on Nov 22, 2019
Ah, now I remember what this means: "This is a false message. What really happened is that your app silently terminated (maybe by a console abort(), i.e.: crashed ) and when the app failed to launch (aborted) the front end gave that message. You need to look at the Windows Console window in VS while in debug mode."